# Why is there a power loss in my small engine motorcycle at a certain RPM range?

Tags: motorcycle, power, small-engine, clutch-plate

I own a TVS Apache RTR 160 (a single cylinder, air-cooled, carburetor motorcycle.) with close to 35000 kilometers.

The bikes loses power in 2nd and higher gears, between 5-6.5k RPM. It loses power no matter how much I open the throttle. It is normal up to 5k RPM and above 6.5k RPM.

There has been no considerable increase in fuel consumption. The gear does slip at times, but not all the time.

I tried changing the spark plug, but to no avail.

**Is it a failing clutch plate or a pulsar coil?**  Could it be something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible causes:

- Worn clutch plate.
- Clogged air filter.
- Clogged carb/fuel delivery system.
- loose chain/issue with chain sprocket.

As for your gear slipping, tighten the clutch , it happened to me too when I used to own the same motorcycle.

Comment: It was indeed worn clutch plates. And the timely adjustment of the tappet fixed the issue.